# Properties file: Comment on the same line as a property

Tags: java, ant

I have a properties file like so

```
a=The letter a
```

say in environment.myproperties which I am using as an argument like so

```
<replace file="${environment.FILETHATNEEDSREPLACE}" replacefilterfile="${environment.myproperties}" />
```

is it possible to have a comment on the same line as a property like this?

```
a=The letter a #comments go here
```

Answer (score 3):

No, a Java properties files cannot have lines with both a key-element pair and comments.

From the [java.util.Properties documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html):

> A comment line has an ASCII '#' or '!' as its first non-white space
>   character

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. You even cannot get normal comments from properties, unless you implement that yourself.

For programmatic access to some form of metadata/comment: make an additional entry:

```
a = The letter a
a# = Comment on a

b = The letter b
b# = To b or not to b
```

By the way, names of Unicode code points, like letters, can be gotten from

```
String letterA = Character.getName((int) 'a');
```